# Bulk update of Magento Category Images

Tags: image, magento, import, thumbnails, categories

I have imported over 400 categories into a Magento install. 
Each category has multiple products, but no category image.

I have written a script to loop through every category and return the URL of the image of the first product within the current category.

The next step is to set the returned product image as the image for it's parent category.

My first approach was to format a CSV with category ID and category image URL for use with MAGMI, however after examining the documentation at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_categories I have been unable to find any information on importing category images. Is this possible with MAGMI?

Failing the above, my next approach was to programmatically set the category image using PHP.
I have located the following snippet which I intend to modify if the MAGMI approach fails. Can anyone confirm if the $image parameter of the setThumbnail method will accept a fully qualified URL or does this refer solely to a local file path ?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
$category->setImage($image);
$category->save();
```

All input greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I was unable to find a solution using MAGMI that allowed me to import category images.
Instead, I arrived at a PHP solution that:

1. Loops through all Magento Product Categories
2. Saves a random (or defined) image from a Product within the current category
3. Updates the current category image with the image saved in step 2.

Here is the code in its entirety which some of you may find useful if dealing with a similar task.

```
<?php

/* require the necessary magento classes */

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

/* construct a category tree object to traverse */

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();

$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$arr = array(); 

/* loop through each category id */

if ($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        getImageForCategory($id);
        updateCategoryThumbnail($id);
    }
}

function getImageForCategory($id){

        $images = array();

        $catId=$id; // put your category ID in here
        $products =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
        ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId));

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($products); // Only select products that are salable

        $products->load();


        foreach($products as $product){
            $images[] = $product->getImageUrl();

            /* remove the following break if you want to use a random image, otherwise the image of the first product will be used. Using random images will cause the execution time to increase dramatically.  */
            break;
        }


        if (sizeof($images) > 1) {
        $random_image = array_rand($images, 1);
        } else {
        $random_image = 0;
        }

        if($images[$random_image]){
            saveImageFromURL($images[$random_image],$id);       
        }

    }

function updateCategoryThumbnail($cat){

    $image = $cat . ".jpg";

    $catc = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
    $catc->setImage($image); // /media/catalog/category
    $catc->save(); 
}

function saveImageFromURL($imgUrl,$cat){


    $fout = fopen('/var/www/vhosts/your-site-folder.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/' . $cat . '.jpg', 'w');
    $fin = fopen($imgUrl, "rb");
    while (!feof($fin)) {
        $buffer= fread($fin, 32*1024);
        fwrite($fout,$buffer);
    }
    fclose($fin);
    fclose($fout);
}
```

?>

Ensure there are sufficient write permissions on the category image folder used in the saveImageFromURL() function.

As above, removing the 'break' statement from the getImageForCategory() will select a category product at random. It should be noted that this will drastically increase the script execution time.